# How to load stylesheets asynchronously (with loadCSS)

Tags: css, django-pipeline

how can I load my stylesheets with loadCSS (https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS)?

Currently I am including the javascript of loadCSS with a template tag like that into my head. I just surrounded my default css with the noscript tags as a fallback (As described in the documentation).

```
<head>        
    ...
    <noscript>
        {% stylesheet "main" %}
    </noscript>

    ...
    <script>
        {% include "components/loadCSS.js" %}
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

But how can I generate an output like that?

```
<link rel="preload" href="path/to/mystylesheet.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

Can I somehow get the links (within href) in my template?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

## Custom Templatetag

```
from django import template
from pipeline.templatetags.pipeline import StylesheetNode
from pipeline.utils import guess_type
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
register = template.Library()

class MyStylesheetNode(StylesheetNode):

    def render_css(self, package, path):
        template_name = "pipeline/loadcss.html"
        context = package.extra_context
        context.update({
            'type': guess_type(path, 'text/css'),
            'url': mark_safe(staticfiles_storage.url(path))
        })
        return render_to_string(template_name, context)

@register.tag
def mytest(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, name = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            '%r requires exactly one argument: the name of a group in the PIPELINE.JAVASVRIPT setting' %
            token.split_contents()[0])
    return MyStylesheetNode(name)
```

## /pipeline/loadcss.html

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{ url }}" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```